# Air conditional protection in winter

Tags: air-conditioning, furnace

My house has a air conditioner,I am not sure I should call it furnace or air conditioner. it works as a air conditioner in summer but work as a heater in winter.

Today I found the condensing unit (the part outside the house) actually doesn't spin during heating process, so I am thinking about if we need to add some plastic to protect snow/rain into it.

But I am not sure weather the heating process need the condensing unit air or not.Should I just cover a plastic bag onto condensing unit in winter?

Comment: It is called a heat pump.  It does use the condenser unit during the heating phase (it gets the heat from outside via the condenser), I haven't had contact with one that didn't spin the fan, but limiting its access to outside air would seem to decrease its efficiency.

Comment: Well, that's if it *is* a heat pump and not just a standard condenser that's part of a split system. As the OP has to deal with snow, I wouldn't think it is, but I've never even seen one. You have, but not one that didn't spin the fan, so there's that too. Regardless, don't cover it...

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've never known of anyone to cover their outdoor a/c equipment. A quick Google found most saying no and a few saying yes...conditionally. [This page](http://asm-air.com/airconditioning/cover-air-conditioner-winter/) summarizes their opinion as:

> Should you cover your air conditioner in the winter?  Probably not,
>   but it’s worth a thought during hails and heavy winter storms.  Your
>   air conditioner is one of your most expensive investments, so take
>   care of it and service it properly.  I will say, one last time, that
>   covering your air conditioner in the winter is not a necessary
>   precaution in most cases.

It's worth pointing out, however, that they seem to be a heating and air company in California.

[This page](https://www.angieslist.com/articles/should-i-cover-my-ac-cold-weather.htm), which is a company in Wisconsin notes:

> In my opinion, it's best to leave the A/C unit uncovered. In the
>   spring, our company handles more repairs for units that were covered
>   during the winter.

..that's a compelling thought.

But you do have a valid concern with respect to seasonal maintenance. It would be wise to do some research on seasonal maintenance for outside compressors going into the Spring, prior to their return to use after a winter hiatus. I imagine checking for and cleaning away any debris at the least.